# Facebook not reading open graph tags if shared url has trailing slash

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have noticed that if i share links with trailing slash facebook won't read correctly open graph tag in the head of my page. Ex.

http://www.daringtodo.com/lang/it/2013/05/23/cinema-nel-weekend-trame-e-trailer-13/

For dynamic writing of these tags i use Facebook Open Graph protocol plugin v2.0.7.

Removing trailing slash solve the issue...

How this is possible? is it possible to make open graph tag work correctly keeping trailing slash in the urls?

Comment: Debug tool shows your OG info being read perfectly: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.daringtodo.com%2Flang%2Fit%2F2013%2F05%2F23%2Fcinema-nel-weekend-trame-e-trailer-13%2F

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

Set your ## og:title ## url in your MetaTag to exactly your canvas url to your app/game.
So what I saw was missing is this '?'

Hopes it works. An answer I'd get after a week's traction :(